# react-router v6 dynamic path RegExp

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

in react-router v5, I was able to specify a certain set of dynamic path properties in the following way:
**'/some-path/:someDynamicProperty(value1|value2|value3)'**
thus the only existing options for this path would be:

- **/some-path/value1**
- **/some-path/value2**
- **/some-path/value3**

any other path(like **/some-path/value1124**) would be treated as an unknown path and caught by a * path

are there any alternatives in react-router v6?

I've checked the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route), but actually found nothing about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Router v6 removed path regular expressions. You can read more about it in ["What Happened to Regexp Routes Paths?"](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-regexp-routes-paths).

If you would like to limit the routes that are matchable then you've a couple options.

1. Explicitly render the routes you want to render. You can map an array of the dynamic path segment values to discrete routes.

   ```
   <Routes>
     ....
     {["value1", "value2", "value3"].map((someDynamicProperty) => (
       <Route
         key={someDynamicProperty}
         path={generatePath("/some-path/:someDynamicProperty", {
           someDynamicProperty
         })}
         element={<MyComponent />}
       />
     ))}
     ...
     <Route path="/404" element={<NotFound />} />
     <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
   </Routes>
   ```
2. Use a dynamic path segment that matches anything and perform the check in the component, redirecting if it is not a valid path segment.

   ```
   <Routes>
     <Route
       path="/some-segment/:someDynamicProperty"
       element={<MyComponent />}
     />
     <Route path="/404" element={<NotFound />} />
     <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
   </Routes>
   ```

   ```
   const MyComponent = () => {
     const { someDynamicProperty } = useParams();
     const match = /(value1|value2|value3)/.test(someDynamicProperty);

     if (!match) return <Navigate to="/404" replace />;

     return (
       ....
     );
   };
   ```